# how to fix jammed integrated dishwasher door?

Tags: dishwasher

It seems something has happened to my dishwasher so I can now only open the door halfway, before it starts jamming.

The wooden facia on the front of the door is unaligned by a centimeter or two, meaning the facia jams against the surrounding cupboard units

If I peek through the gap between the facia and the dishwasher front, I can see some sort of metal bracket, but I dont know how to remove or realign the facia.

Any ideas please? Sorry if its a bad description, its kinda a weird problem which happened while I was away from home for a week

Comment: Find the manual for your appliance, it will provide instructions on how the panel mounts to the dishwasher

Comment: Its an OKO Favorit (it appears OKO is a foreign name for AEG). I've viewed a few manuals for OKO Favorit, but none of them mention anything about the facia. I cannot find the exact model number I have, but Ive a sneaking suspicion it might be on a label underneath the facia. So back to square one. I was hoping these integrated dishwashers had some sort of standard way of fitting though

Comment: We could only wish they were standard :) If it helps, on my dishwasher, on the inside of the door, there are 3 screws on each side which are used to secure the door panel

Comment: Thanks Steven, Ill look for some screws on inside. But I had a real job even squeezing a clean fork out the dishwasher, so if the screws are anywhere near the base of the door, I think Im in trouble :)

Comment: Have you tried forcing the door panel back to the correct position?

Comment: yeah, it wont seem to move, although its difficult to get much leverage on it since I cant open the door :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was moved out of alignment, you should be able to move it back into the correct alignment to allow you to open the dishwasher door again.

If you cannot get a decent grip on the door sides to force it, you can try using a [glass suction cup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003QW0PXQ) to get a hold of it and force it back into position.

[image: Glass Suction Cup]

Comment: its a wooden door front rather than glass. The problem is whilst I can grab the door facia, the manouvre I need to make to get it back into position isnt obvious.  Thanks for the advice though, Im thinking I cant explain it well enough (and its too obscure a problem) for it be sorted over the net

Comment: You can use this on any surface really, it's not limited to glass

Comment: I finally got to the bottom of the problem. What has happened is the stopcock under my kitchen sink has been dripping while I was away. This meant the cupboard adjacent to the dishwasher became soaked, and swelled up. This caused the dishwasher door to start jamming against the side of it when opening

Comment: But then it gets worse. In my attempts to force the door open, it pulled the dishwasher forward slightly, and the 4 plastic legs which the dishwasher was raised up on, snapped clean off. Of course this wasnt that obvious at the time, because its all hidden behind kick plates.

Comment: Finally, Im marking your answer as correct, because as it turns out, nobody could have helped me over the net, but I appreciate you at least trying :-) Thanks